# Problems with paste location range

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there i have a code which copies columns based on a given criteria and pastes to another sheet. I want to change the paste location ,whereby it should start pasting from `"C5"` `WF-4 CC with  Values` sheet but I am unable to do so . It gives selection method fail errors.  Would need some help on how I can change the paste range location . Thank you:) This is the code :

```
Sub ExtractCCData4()

    Dim lastcol As Long
    Dim j As Long

    With Worksheets("WF - L4")
        lastcol = .Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For j = 3 To lastcol
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Columns(j)) > 0 Then
                .Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("WF-4 CC with  Values").Columns(j)
            Else

            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarifications

I'm assuming

- *"it should start pasting from "C5"*  means that the it pastes from "C5" rightwards seamlessly with no regards to "WF - L4" columns skipping
- you only need to paste values

then try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractCCData4()

    Dim lastcol As Long
    Dim j As Long, jPaste As Long
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    With Worksheets("WF - L4")
        lastcol = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For j = 3 To lastcol
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Columns(j)) > 0 Then
                Set rngToCopy = .Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp))

                Worksheets("WF-4 CC with  Values").Range("C5").Offset(, jPaste).Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value
                jPaste = jPaste + 1 '<~~ updating column offsetting from "WF - L4" sheet column "C"
            Else

            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It runs but the paste location sheet is blank

Comment: what does "pasting from C5 onwards" actually mean? the first time it paste from C5, the second time from D5 even if it skipped more columns in "WF - L4" sheet? or what?

Comment: yup it is what you just said!

Comment: it is not running is as wide a statement as it is useless. try your best to narrow it down to actual input and outputs

Comment: see edited code, if I _guessed_ it correctly. otherwise give precise and detailed data to describe what's going wrong

Comment: works perfectly. thank you so much:) however it starts from c9 instead of c5.

Comment: you are welcome. not sure if the "C9-C5" is an issue or simply something you had to change